# Android Syncronize Data across devices

Tags: android

I am building an android application for which I need some  data to  be accessible on any device user logs in.The data should be available on his mobile / tablet or any device in which he logs in using his gmail account.

Any idea / suggestions / best practises on how to go about this.

Does the API provide any out of box solution for this or do I have to go with something of my own.

Comment: You'll need to put the data in "the cloud." There are many ways to do this, but any answer you solicit here will be opinion-based, and less than perfect for you, as we don't know what your data looks like. Firebase is a great tool that takes the complexity out of it, and data is "just there." Other approaches might fit your requirements better.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest storing the data on a server (RESTful).

If you do not have a server, take a look at parse.com .